# Trying to send command for object without authority

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, command, authority, unity-networking

I'm instantiating a GameObject (a Canvas) that have a child (MoveRightBtn) with a Event Trigger "Pointer Down".
It is a button that when touched I should move my player. But when touched occurs this error:

Trying to send command for object without authority.

```
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour:SendCommandInternal(NetworkWriter, Int32, String)
playerShoot:CallCmdMove(Single)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

What is wrong?

**Code**:

public class playerShoot : NetworkBehaviour {

```
public GameObject buttons;

void Start () {
    NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority ((GameObject)Instantiate (buttons), connectionToClient);
}

void Update () {

}

[Command]
void CmdMove(float horizontalInput){
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
}
```

}

**Player**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RN1V.png

**Canvas**: http:// i .stack.imgur.com/zu8Ax.png

**Canvas child**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXwTy.png

Comment: `unity` is not `unity3d`